# Installing GitHub python package into Anaconda, Spyder

Tags: python, git, github, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to install https://github.com/esiivola/GPYgradients/tree/grad_obs.git and use it in Anaconda's spyder. I want this version of GPy to overwrite what I install when running "pip install GPy". 
I have tried "!pip install -e git+https://github.com/esiivola/GPYgradients/tree/grad_obs.git#egg=GPyGradient" withing spyder. It gives me an error: Command "git clone -q https://github.com/esiivola/GPYgradients/tree/grad_obs.git C:\Users...\src\gpygradient" failed with error code 128 in None. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of the links you have provided work can you fix them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tar ball:

```
pip install https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/master.tar.gz
```

Instead of master, you can give any other branch or release tag.

Comment: so in my case that would be !pip install https://github.com/esiivola/GPYgradients/tree/grad_obs/archive/master.tar.gz this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct URL is `https://$HOST/repo@commit#egg=module`. `repository` is `/esiivola/GPYgradients.git`, commit is `grad_obs` which is a branch (could be a tag or a commit ID).

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/esiivola/GPYgradients.git@grad_obs#egg=GPyGradient
```